# componentDidUpdate vs componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I need to make sure an input element is focused when the following is true:

- DOM is available
- and properties got changed

Question: Do I need to put my code in both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` or just `componentDidUpdate` would be suffice?

```
    private makeSureInputElementFocused() {
        if (this.props.shouldGetInputElementFocused && this.inputElement !== null) {
            this.inputElement.focus();
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.makeSureInputElementFocused(); // <-- do i need this?
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.makeSureInputElementFocused();
    }
```

Answer (score 41):

You have to use both.

[componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

[componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. **This method is not called for the initial render**.

You also could place it into the `render()` method which seems like it's appropriate for your case since you always want to check the focus. Then you don't need to put it into `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: Assuming that `inputElement` refers to a DOM node produced by React using `render`'s return value, how could you interact with this DOM node in the body of `render` before that return value is provided to React?

Answer (score 13):

Each of your conditions require you to place the code inside 1 function each:

- the DOM is available and - `componentDidMount`
- properties got changed - `componentDidUpdate`

So you have to place inside both functions.
Another option is to call `setState()` inside `componentDidMount`, so that `componentDidUpdate` is invoked.

Answer (score 5):

**componentDidMount()**

[componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) will be invoked immediately after a component is mounted. This method will render only once and all the initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

**componentDidUpdate()**

[componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is invoked immediately every time the updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

You can understands more from this below example

```
import React from 'react';

class Example extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    //This function will call on initial rendering.
    document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;

  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
     document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
   }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Example;
```

You can understand by commenting and un-commenting both methods.

Answer (score 4):

`componentDidUpdate` is not called at initial render (see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) so you probably must call it twice as in your example.

Answer (score 3):

In React v16.7.0-alpha you can use the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function InputField() {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  });

  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
}
```

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
>   of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
>   componentWillUnmount combined.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/04jjrjk66v)

Note: as mentioned, this will not work with class based components.

Comment: This does not answer the question and will not work with class based components.

Comment: This is for Functional components not Class based ones.