# what is difference between componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I cant understand what is difference between `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`

I saw some counter app that use `setState` method for increasing count value inside `componentDidMount` so what if we write setState inside `componentDidUpdate`?

and when should we use `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [componentDidUpdate vs componentDidMount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686386/componentdidupdate-vs-componentdidmount)

Comment: this is what [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) are for

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From [the docs on the component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html):

- `componentDidMount()`: invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the DOM tree)
- `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`:  is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render. Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated.

To make it simple, the first is called at the beginning, and the second upon every change. They are absolutely not interchangeable.

About using `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate`: **beware**! Using `setState` calls `componentDidUpdate`, so you might end up with an infinite loop if you call `setState` at *every invocation of `componentDidUpdate`.

Oh and also, here's [a cool diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) to sum up the whole component lifecycle.

Answer (score 3):

**componentDidMount()**

componentDidMount() will be rendered immediately after a component is mounted. This method will render only once and all the initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

**componentDidUpdate()**

componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately every time the updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

You can understand more from this below example

```
import React from 'react';

class Example extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    //This function will call on initial rendering.
    document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;

  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
     document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
   }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Example;
```

You can understand by commenting and un-commenting both life cycle methods.